# Getting error while popping in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

I have a dictionary

```
price={'10MAR23': 113.49999999999999,
 '3MAR23': 19.10000000000001,
 '25FEB23': 19.100000000000012,
 '28APR23': 3.5,
 '26FEB23': 0.4,
 '31MAR23': 27.5,
 '17MAR23': 3.1}
```

I want to replace the keys with respective dates with format as %d%m%y like

```
100323
030323
250223
280423
260223
310323
170323
```

The following code does that,

```
for i in price:
        new_key=datetime.datetime.strptime(i,'%d%b%y').strftime('%d%m%y')
        price[new_key]=price.pop(i)
```

but getting error like

```
ValueError: time data '030323' does not match format '%d%b%y'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are looping over `price` while modifying its keys at the same time. You can avoid that by copying the dictionary before performing the loop, with `for i in dict(price):`, as so:

```py
price = {'10MAR23': 113.49999999999999,
         '3MAR23': 19.10000000000001,
         '25FEB23': 19.100000000000012,
         '28APR23': 3.5,
         '26FEB23': 0.4,
         '31MAR23': 27.5,
         '17MAR23': 3.1}

for i in dict(price):
    new_key = datetime.datetime.strptime(i,'%d%b%y').strftime('%d%m%y')
    price[new_key] = price.pop(i)
```

Alternatively, you can create a new dictionary from the old one with a dictionary comprehension

```py
price = {datetime.datetime.strptime(k, '%d%b%y').strftime('%d%m%y'): v 
         for k, v in price.items()}
```

Comment: ok, cant they be modified at same time and 'dict(price)' is copying the data into new one?

Comment: @Madan if you modify the keys while looping over them, the iterator will loop over the modified keys as well, which shows you the error when trying to parse the date, as the format no longer matches, and yes `dict(price)` makes a copy of the dictionary - you can also do a copy with `price.copy()`

Comment: got it, this is helpful. Knowing about runtime change of the loop and values